# Does Geopackage field length affect performance?

Tags: performance, fields-attributes, geopackage

I have moved away from shapefiles, and now store most of my desktop spatial data in a Geopackage. One of my fields is used to store research notes and is 'Type TEXT' with a character limit of 254.

I would very much like to increase this limit so that I can write more detailed notes and know how to do this within the DB Manager in QGIS.

I have no idea if it will but I assume that a large body of text for each attribute (approximately 12,000) would hinder performance significantly. What I would like to know is, should I be cautious of how high I set the threshold in terms of performance of the layer?

Comment: To answer performance questions I think the best way is to performance test.

Comment: Of course as PolyGeo wrote, the only way of knowing exactly is performance testing. But some sidenotes: Sqlite has a defualt text length limit of 1bio. That can be changed in the options easily. In opposite to the shapefile it does also not matter if the string is empty. It is only the amount of space used that is needed. Sqlite DB are working fine with several GB of data (using several large GeoPackages here without problems). I don´t think you need to worry about texts in this range.